# IIS 7 issue - the server session mixed to different users

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webserver

Please help on our issue on the user session. After log-in and select a menu, it will fall on the different user session.

The normal URL should be like this:
http://www.company.com/mams/Sales/AccountForecasting.aspx

But it goes to this URL:
http://www.company.com/mams/(X(1)S(hm4occ2bbcefegbj1gws4kwf))/Sales/AccountForecasting.aspx

Notice that there is a script inside the URL and im not sure where it came from.

After i recycle the application pool and restart the website, it will back to normal but this problem will occur again after 1 or 2 days after restart.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a cookieless session to me.  Most likely you're running an older version of .net and the browser file isn't recognizing a newer browser, so it's defaulting to cookieless.

One option to fix is to set session to always use cookies. (cookieless="UseCookies" from the configuring session link).

Another option is to use a browser files to modify the default capabilities of the problem browser.  It would require some knowledge of which browsers is causing the problem.  Or you could configure all downlevel browsers to default to supporting cookies. (See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx)

On cookieless sessions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

On configuring session
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx